# Calibrate Gazebo Camera

Tags: ros, gazebo, calibration, ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have a robot in a gazebo environment. This robot has a camera (I use the *libgazebo_ros_prosilica.so* controller).

I have to use *ar_pose* to get the robot position in gazebo world through camera acquisition. But I have a big problem: **how can I calibrate that camera?** There is some ar_pose internal tools or I have to search for more esoteric solutions?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28957/calibrate-gazebo-camera/) by [thek3nger](https://answers.ros.org/users/1169/thek3nger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2012-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Intrinsic calibration is not really required in gazebo since we do not inject any distortion to the image.  You can see how the projection matrix is setup in [`GazeboRosCamera::PublishCameraInfo()`](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.4/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_camera.cpp).

Extrinsic calibration is also not necessary as you should be able to access the exact pose of the camera sensor in simulation through either the ROS API or using tf.

But if you really wanted to run through the calibration procedure, you'll have to create a checkerboard in simulation and run through [camera calibration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration), or you can see how the [pr2 cameras are calibrated here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrating%20the%20PR2%27s%20Cameras).

Please let me know if any of the above is unclear.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set the intrinsic calibration parameters of your camera in the camera configuration xml belonging to your urdf model (see [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11965/using-camera-sensor-in-gazebo) for an example). The plugin also publishes a camera info topic, that should contain the intrinsic parameters.

The extrinsic parameters are generally known, because you select where the camera is mounted.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-03-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arshad](https://answers.ros.org/users/103409/arshad/) on 2022-12-06**:
This may be useful for anyone doing camera calibration in Gazebo ROS2
https://medium.com/@arshad.mehmood/camera-calibration-in-gazebo-ros2-6bed2620a652